# CSV Wrong Encoding UTF-8

Tags: android, csv, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

I am building an app, and I have a need for names of cities.

I have found a CSV and an XML file on this site:

https://data.gov.il/dataset/citiesandsettelments

The app is in Hebrew, and I need the database on this site.

So I downloaded the CSV file which is in UTF-8.

When I copied it into Android Studio's res/raw folder, this is the result:

[image: "The Question Mark Mayhem"]

You can see clearly that the English names for the cities are fine, but all others which are written in Hebrew are messed up.

**What should I do to prevent this error?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the problem
i changed the encoding into windows 1255 and it works fine.

sorry for this.